# C# Delphi ComPort Communication

Tags: c#, delphi

I use Visual Studio 2008 (C#) or Delphi CodeGear and made program that communicate with serial com port device.
The device send me data in hex format and i read it.Real example - 40 32 00 D2 01 A6 B2 
First byte "40" is number of device.
Second byte "32" is which button of device was pressed.
etc....

My question is how to look bytes separately.When i receive 40 32 00 D2 01 A6 B2 
i have to say that this is device '1'(for example) and it was pressed button '2'(for example).
If somebody know how to do that i would be very thankful for some help.Thank you

Comment: You say you "read it". How do you read it (in what format - string, byte array, ??)?

Comment: Can you post some code (just the part where you read the incoming data).

Answer (score 0):

I found this code and use it :

```
void comPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            //determine the mode the user selected (binary/string)
            switch (CurrentTransmissionType)
            {
                //user chose string
                case TransmissionType.Text:
                    //read data waiting in the buffer
                    string msg = comPort.ReadExisting();
                    //display the data to the user
                    DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, msg + "\n");
                    break;
                //user chose binary
                case TransmissionType.Hex:
                    //retrieve number of bytes in the buffer
                    int bytes = comPort.BytesToRead;
                    //create a byte array to hold the awaiting data
                    byte[] comBuffer = new byte[bytes];
                    //read the data and store it
                    comPort.Read(comBuffer, 0, bytes);
                    //display the data to the user
                    DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, ByteToHex(comBuffer) + "\n");
                    break;
                default:
                    //read data waiting in the buffer
                    string str = comPort.ReadExisting();
                    //display the data to the user
                    DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, str + "\n");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

And i Receive this "40 32 00 D2 01 A6 B2" (HEX format) I want to that first byte means that this device is Number 1 ,second byte means that Button number N is pressed etc. ....

Comment: Select the code, press the `{}` button above the editor or `Ctrl+K`.

Comment: Alternatively: `<pre><code> your block of code </code></pre>`.